# Blazor standalone WebAssembly call secure core API on behalf of logged in user

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, azure-active-directory, blazor, webapi

I have a secure API app set up in AAD with couple of scopes.
I also have a standalone Blazor client that I want to make requests from to my API.
I have a user with access to my API scopes.
My Client has delegated permissions to my API - all of the scopes.

When I add `app.MapControllers().AllowAnonymous();` I am getting data back in my Blazor client. All works fine. When I remove that line, I am getting 404. I have been trying for 5 days to solve this and am resigned at this point. I am able to login to the application using my user that I created in AAD, when I make the request, I can see in the fiddler that bearer token is in the header... I always get 404 back, not even 401 or 403.

This is my Api configuration:

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApi(builder.Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"));
```

This is my client configuration:

```
builder.Services.AddMsalAuthentication(options =>
{
    builder.Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options.ProviderOptions.Authentication);
    options.ProviderOptions.DefaultAccessTokenScopes.Add("https://graph.microsoft.com/User.Read");
});

builder.Services.AddScoped<CustomAuthorizationMessageHandler>();

builder.Services.AddHttpClient("WebAPI",
        client => client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://localhost:5101/"))
    .AddHttpMessageHandler<CustomAuthorizationMessageHandler>();
```

and the handler:

```
   public class CustomAuthorizationMessageHandler : AuthorizationMessageHandler
    {
        public CustomAuthorizationMessageHandler(IAccessTokenProvider provider,
            NavigationManager navigationManager)
            : base(provider, navigationManager)
        {
            ConfigureHandler(
                authorizedUrls: new[] { "https://localhost:5101/" },
                scopes: new[] { "api://38019b82-84d0-40cc-a2cd-155f2d8b7757/API.RO1" });
        }
    }
```

I am calling the api as follows from my page:

```
var client = ClientFactory.CreateClient("WebAPI");
entries = await client.GetFromJsonAsync<List<TimeSeriesEntry>>("/api/tds/2022-08-06");
```

Could you please tell me if see anything obviously wrong with this config ?

Comment: if it is any help I decoded the token from the header using `https://jwt.ms/` and I can see my scopes and user roles are carried with request...

Comment: Did you remove `MapControllers()` or just `AllowAnonymous()`? `app.MapControllers();` should not be removed.

Comment: I'm an idiot. Please post it as an answer and I will accept...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't remove the whole line `app.MapControllers().AllowAnonymous();`. `app.MapControllers();` is essential for web api to work.